# arrange data according to timestamp newer to older

Tags: mysql

Hello i made a query in which i am arranging data according to the current date but the problem is the result is coming in the form of older to newer . how i can i achieve this by newer to older . here is my query

```
$date = "select CAST(post_date AS DATE) AS dated from wp_hdflvvideoshare  group by dated order by (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 20 DAY))";
 $date_sql=$wpdb->get_results($date);
```

Like i am getting results in form of

> oct nov dec

i want it in

> dec nov oct

Comment: `(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 20 DAY))` is a constant date. It is not related to the rows and therefore it won't alter the sorting.

Comment: so how can i make this work ?

Comment: Post sample data and expected output.

Comment: hello @SalmanA thanks for the reply i already have put up a structure of what i am getting and what i want

Comment: `ORDER BY 1 DESC` might work but I cannot say for sure until you show us some sample values from `post_date` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRy this ::

```
select CAST(post_date AS DATE) AS dated from wp_hdflvvideoshare  group by dated 
order by dated desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $date = "select CAST(post_date AS DATE) AS dated
          from wp_hdflvvideoshare
          group by dated
          order by dated DESC";
```

Comment: its repeating everything again n again in each month result

Comment: try this http://82.157.70.109/mirrorbooks/mysqlcertification/0672326329/ch05lev1sec3.html

Comment: @ParamVeer Post some sample data and the expected output in your question, because I think this should work. It shouldn't repeat any dates because of the `GROUP BY` clause. It will show different dates in the same month.